# Remove duplicates in Linked List

Tags: c++, linked-list

I dont know whats wrong with my code. Also, how would you delete a node in the linked list.

```
for( IntNode* i = head; i != 0; i = i->next ) {

        IntNode* prev = i;
        for( IntNode* j = i->next; j != 0; j = j->next ) {

            if( j->data == i->data ) {

                IntNode* temp = j;
                prev->next = j->next;
                delete temp;
            }
            prev = prev->next;
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Dai Either C or C++

Comment: What is the behavior that makes you think it is wrong? Also make a node delete routine!

Comment: The problem is that the inner loop will access the deleted node memory with the for loop increment part -> j=j->next

Comment: You can also refer the link http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/remove-duplicates-from-an-unsorted-linked-list/ for understanding about the algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Im going to take a shot in the dark here and say that you having memory troubles?

The reason i think this is because if you delete a node you are left with the dangling memory of `j`.

you need to have the following:

```
IntNode* temp = 
prev->next = j->next;
j = j->next;
delete temp;
```

and you will need to modify your `for` loop. Consider the following:

```
IntNode *j = i->next;
while (j != 0) {
    if( j->data == i->data ) {
        //As above
    } else {
        j = j->next;
    }
    prev = prev->next;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are forgetting to set 'j'.

```html
for (IntNode* i = head; i != 0; i = i->next) {

 IntNode* prev = i;
 for (IntNode* j = i->next; j != 0; j = j->next) {

  if (j->data == i->data) {

   IntNode* temp = j;
   prev->next = j->next;
   j = prev;
   delete temp;
  }
  else
  {
   prev = prev->next;
  }
 }
}
```